# Correct way to specify 'path' in Jquery I18N plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, internationalization

I wanted to implement client-side internationalization in my ASP.NET MVC application. So I used this jQuery plugin called [jQuery i18n](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-i18n-properties/).

I have my .properties files in a directory called `I18NProperties`, which is in my root directory, which also contains other MVC folders like `Views` and `Controllers`.

Now, while invoking the plugin, I do this:

```
$.i18n.properties({
    name: 'Messages',
    path: 'I18NProperties/',
    mode: 'both',
    language: someVar,
    callback: function () {
        alert($.i18n.prop('msg_success'));
    }
});
```

`msg_success` is a key in my .properties file.

However, when the callback function is executed, the alert box displays the key instead of the value, like this: `[msg_success]`.

When I replaced `alert($.i18n.prop('msg_success'))` with `alert(msg_success)`, the alert box did not show up, as no JavaScript variable called `msg_success` was created.

So my guess is that the plugin is unable to find the .properties files.

What is the correct way to specify the value of the path parameter? I also tried `path: '~\I18NProperties\`, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it will not work.. Jquery plugin will always look for properties file which are within webcontent folder. Try this which will fix your problem..

1. Copy those properties file inside your Webcontent folder and test it with actual path. e.g. resources/custom/i18n/ [Note - Here i places properties file inside i18n folder and placed resources folder under Webcontent]. This will fix your problem!!
2. Now comes how we can manage 2 files and do we really need it? Easiest to do is have your file only under src/main/resources folder, but as part of your build step copy these properties file to your second location(i.e. inside Webcontent folder).

Hope this helps :)